# Azure: Unable to attach my data disk to VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, disk, vhd

I have a Linux VM running in US West. I had a 250GB disk attached to it corresponding to a vhd. There was an Azure storage account outage today and I am unable to attach the same disk again. When I attach a disk it does not give me the option to add this disk that is supposed to have the data, rather it has created a new 250GB vhd which is empty and gave me an option to attach that. The original vhd has customer data and would love to retrieve it.

Other data points and questions,

1) I am hoping the original vhd has the latest customer data as we were keeping it as the disk store for our db writes and reads. Will this vhd be up-to-date?

2) For some reason, the image I use to create any VM has both the OS disk and this 250GB disk. Is this the source of the problem?

3) When I try to create a new disk from the original vhd, it gives an error "The VHD xxxxxxxxxxx.vhd is already registered with image repository as the resource with ID yyyyyyyyyyy."

4) I tried deleting the VM and the disk. But I am unable to delete the image. The delete button in the images tab is not enabled.

This is causing downtime for us. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check. The 250GB Disk that you had attached to the VM orginally before the outage, it wouldnt be the temporary drive that is provided with any VM provisioned on Azure isnt it?

If it was part of the temporary drive, then all data on the drive gets wiped as the VM Power Cycles/ reboots etc.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2013/12/07/understanding-the-temporary-drive-on-windows-azure-virtual-machines.aspx

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, if that was the case.